# why use transpose than directly set array?

Tags: python, numpy

In a python code I see two lines below (initially, labels was of type (15093, that is, 1-d array)(from py-faster-rcnn)

```
labels = labels.reshape((1, height, width, A)).transpose(0, 3, 1, 2)
labels = labels.reshape((1, 1, A * height, width))
```

Is there any reason the author use transpose than directly set

```
labels = labels.reshape((1, A, height, width))
labels = labels.reshape((1, 1, A * height, width))
```

Or even,

```
labels = labels.reshape((1, 1, A * height, width))
```

?  (I guess it's related to the data order in the initial labels array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is quite easy : yes there is a reason, given the same `labels` array, the results of your 3 methods simply aren't the same.

Lets check that with an example:

```
import numpy as np
height, width, A = [2,3,4]
arr=np.random.rand(1*height*width*A)

print("Method 1")
labels1=np.copy(arr)
labels1 = labels1.reshape((1, height, width, A)).transpose(0, 3, 1, 2)
labels1 = labels1.reshape((1, 1, A * height, width))
print(labels1)

print("Method 2")
labels2=np.copy(arr)
labels2 = labels2.reshape((1, A, height, width))
labels2 = labels2.reshape((1, 1, A * height, width))
print(labels2)

print("Method 3")
labels3=np.copy(arr)
labels3 = labels3.reshape((1, 1, A * height, width))
print(labels3)
```

Which gives:

```
>>> Method 1
>>> [[[[ 0.97360395  0.40639034  0.92936386]
>>>    [ 0.01687321  0.94744919  0.39188023]
>>>    [ 0.34210967  0.36342341  0.6938464 ]
>>>    [ 0.60065943  0.00356836  0.91785409]
>>>    [ 0.57095964  0.61036102  0.17318427]
>>>    [ 0.38002045  0.08596757  0.29407445]
>>>    [ 0.95899964  0.13046103  0.36286533]
>>>    [ 0.86970793  0.11659624  0.82073826]]]]
>>> Method 2
>>> [[[[ 0.97360395  0.34210967  0.57095964]
>>>    [ 0.95899964  0.40639034  0.36342341]
>>>    [ 0.61036102  0.13046103  0.92936386]
>>>    [ 0.6938464   0.17318427  0.36286533]
>>>    [ 0.01687321  0.60065943  0.38002045]
>>>    [ 0.86970793  0.94744919  0.00356836]
>>>    [ 0.08596757  0.11659624  0.39188023]
>>>    [ 0.91785409  0.29407445  0.82073826]]]]
>>> Method 3
>>> [[[[ 0.97360395  0.34210967  0.57095964]
>>>    [ 0.95899964  0.40639034  0.36342341]
>>>    [ 0.61036102  0.13046103  0.92936386]
>>>    [ 0.6938464   0.17318427  0.36286533]
>>>    [ 0.01687321  0.60065943  0.38002045]
>>>    [ 0.86970793  0.94744919  0.00356836]
>>>    [ 0.08596757  0.11659624  0.39188023]
>>>    [ 0.91785409  0.29407445  0.82073826]]]]
```

So method 1 is different from 2 and 3, while 2 and 3 are the same.

Comment: Thanks for the nice example!

Comment: So the data are given meanings when we first reshape the 1-D array, or arranging the data in a meaningful format.